# Issue during elements insertion in a set with py-redis

Tags: redis, redis-py

I have created a set using redis-py:

```
r.sadd('Minutes', "00", "05", "10", "15", "20", "25", "30", "35", "40", "45", "50", "55")
```

When I display it, by:

```
print(r.sscan('Minutes')[1])
```

I get an incomplete (shorter) list:

```
['25', '55', '50', '40', '20', '00', '15', '10', '05', '35']
```

Why this?

Answer (score 2):

You're dealing with a [cursor based iterator](https://redis.io/commands/scan) that, by default, returns 10 values, so you must perform additional scans on the set until the cursor is zero again (the whole set was scanned). The current cursor value, as per your code it's in `[0]`.
If you have a predictable (and reasonable) number of members in the set you can also leverage the `count` option to get everything at once. In `redis-py` it could be something like this:

```
r.sscan('Minutes', count=12)
```

Take a look at the documentation linked above because, as customary in Redis, there's always details to consider (for example, the count option is more of a hint and, not so much, a guarantee).